# Windows API to trigger wallpaper shuffle

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, windows-7

Is there a way to trigger a shuffle in windows wallpaper slideshow?
Preferably something I can use from .net

EDIT: so I'm trying to use the IActiveDesktop interface, I got it from [here](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.interop/msg/9b42ff75078b71c0), I tried to use it like this:

```
public static IActiveDesktop GetActiveDesktop()
{
    Type typeActiveDesktop = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("{75048700-EF1F-11D0-9888-006097DEACF9}"));
    return (IActiveDesktop) Activator.CreateInstance(typeActiveDesktop);
}
```

and then calling it like this:

```
IActiveDesktop dt = GetActiveDesktop();
dt.ApplyChanges(AD_APPLY.ALL | AD_APPLY.FORCE | AD_APPLY.BUFFERED_REFRESH);
```

nothing happens when I run the code, no errors too.

Comment: I doubt if there is an API for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

Your theme located in C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\.theme

Open the .theme file and update a Shuffle flag in the [Slideshow] section:

```
[Slideshow]     
Shuffle=1
```

Then use IActiveDesktop interface to reload theme, call ApplyChange with the following parameters:

AD_APPLY_ALL | AD_APPLY_FORCE | AD_APPLY_BUFFERED_REFRESH

Comment: You should be using the Personalization control panel instead of editing the theme file to toggle shuffling.

Comment: It's not guaranteed that the user's profile will be in a directory corresponding exactly to their username. If I were writing code to solve this problem then I wouldn't rely on the path being consistent. First I'd grab the profile directory of the current user to construct the string.

Comment: I got the interface from [here](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.interop/msg/9b42ff75078b71c0), but it doesn't seem to work, I create a new instance of this `Type typeActiveDesktop = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("{75048700-EF1F-11D0-9888-006097DEACF9}"))`

Answer (score 1):

OH WAIT, just discovered you just want to shuffle. [Flot2011's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853393/windows-api-to-trigger-wallpaper-shuffle/9854826#9854826) is the way to go.

You can find the full path to the current user's theme via:

> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\CurrentTheme

<s>If there's any api for this, it probably won't be exposed yet. Best thing I will do if I were you is to simulate a click of the 'Next desktop background' option in the Desktop Context Menu. There are several ways to do this, but I will suggest you use `GetDesktopWindow` api, simulate a right mouse click and send the 'n' key. I am not completely sure about what effect this will achieve but it should work.</s>

Also take a look at this: http://www.technixupdate.com/keyboard-shortcut-or-hotkey-to-switch-to-next-windows-7-desktop-wallpaper/

Answer (score 0):

The registry key

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Personalization\Desktop Slideshow

contains values which should give you control over several aspects of the feature.

Comment: I've never tried to trigger changes in the current environment by changing those values so I can't guarantee that you'll see an immediate difference after editing them.

Answer (score 0):

If all someone needs is a quick, hacky script, this seems to work for me in powershell, if you don't mind a couple seconds delay and the windows going down and then back up:

```
Function Next-Slide() {

   $shellApp = New-Object -ComObject  Shell.Application
   $wScript = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell

   # stack.push(...)
   # I guess this is assuming we aren't on the desktop already...
   $shellApp.ToggleDesktop();

   # This doesn't seem to be needed...
   #$desktopLoc = $wScript.SpecialFolders('Desktop');
   #$wScript.AppActivate($desktopLoc);

   #Give time to get to the desktop
   sleep 1;

   # Hack to make sure something is selected on the desktop
   # if there is something to select.
   $wScript.SendKeys('{RIGHT}');
   $wScript.SendKeys('{UP}');
   $wScript.SendKeys('{LEFT}');
   $wScript.SendKeys('{DOWN}');

   # Now undo the selection so that we get the desktop context
   # menu, not the icon one. This toggles selection on desktop.
   $wScript.SendKeys("^ ");


   # Open a context menu and select the option to see the next slide
   $wScript.SendKeys("+{F10}");
   $wScript.SendKeys("n");
   $wScript.SendKeys("~"); #This is ENTER

   # Give the key commands time to be read
   sleep 1;

   # stack.pop()
   $shellApp.ToggleDesktop();
}
```

Caveat: I am seeing the numlock on/off indicator pop up on the bottom right of my screen when I run this. I'm not sure why. It may be changing.

Answer (score 0):

I utilize AutoHotkey to call [IDesktopWallpaper::AdvanceSlideshow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-idesktopwallpaper-advanceslideshow?redirectedfrom=MSDN) via COM.  This could also be done programmatically a [variety](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0d4737a9-639c-4648-b437-6fcbaee5c2ae/how-do-i-set-the-wallpaper-background-image-per-desktop-monitor?forum=csharpgeneral) [of](https://github.com/xupefei/Bing-Wallpaper/blob/master/BingWallpaper/DesktopWallpaper.cs) [ways](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/205830-solvedhelp-with-idesktopwallpaper-advanceslideshow/).

I cannot take credit for this AHK implementation, I believe original credit goes to [qwerty12 on the AHK forums](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=159745#p159745):

```
#^w::  ; Ctrl-Win-W to advance to next wallpaper
   try if ((pDesktopWallpaper := ComObjCreate("{C2CF3110-460E-4fc1-B9D0-8A1C0C9CC4BD}", "{B92B56A9-8B55-4E14-9A89-0199BBB6F93B}"))) {
      DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(pDesktopWallpaper+0)+16*A_PtrSize), "Ptr", pDesktopWallpaper, "Ptr", 0, "UInt", 0) ; IDesktopWallpaper::AdvanceSlideshow - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706947(v=vs.85).aspx
      ObjRelease(pDesktopWallpaper)
   }
return
```